# Create and Open new Window and Print Images using JavaScript and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When I try to open and print a window using`JavaScript`'s window.print(), the image doesn't show in `Chrome`, when it prints. My code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openWin()
  {
    var myWindow = window.open('','', 'width=200,height=100');

    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
    myWindow.document.write("<p><img src='https://www.google.gr/images/srpr/logo11w.png' width='400' /></p>");

    myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.print();
    myWindow.close();

 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

And you can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/649/
How can fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The image hasn't been loaded when the call to `print()` is made.

You need to delay the call to `print` until AFTER the image is finished loading. jQuery can do this, so you could include jquery in the page, and then wrap the call to `print` in code like this:

```
function openWin()
{
    var myWindow = window.open('','','width=500,height=500');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
    myWindow.document.write("<p><img src='https://www.google.gr/images/srpr/logo11w.png' width='400' /> </p>");

    myWindow.document.write("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>");
    myWindow.document.write("<script>$(window).load(function(){ print(); });</script>");
}
```

Comment: Where "window" I will add my window name? "myWindow" ? or it is not necessary

Comment: I've edited my answer. Give that a go. JSFiddle doesn't support document.write so don't bother trying it there :-)

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/685/ works but only at first time. Need reload to works again